# python variable sharing between packages/modules

Tags: python

trying to understand and learn how to write packages... testing with something i've always used, logging...

Can you please help me understand why the 'log' variable is not working... and no logging is working on the screen?

Thanks!

main.py :

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python
    import sys
    sys.path.append('CLUSTER')
    import clusterlogging.differentlogging
    clusterlogging.differentlogging.consolelogging()

log.debug("Successfully logged in")
```

differentlogging.py

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python

def consolelogging():
    import logging
    class NullHandler(logging.Handler):
        def emit(self, record):
            pass

print "Console Logging loaded"
DEFAULTLOGLEVEL=logging.INFO

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.addHandler(NullHandler())

log.debug("Successfully logged in")

def mysqllogging():
    print "mysql logging module here"

def sysloglogging():
print "rsyslog logging module here"
```

output

```
Console Logging loaded
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./svnprod.py", line 10, in <module>
    log.debug("Successfully logged in")
NameError: name 'log' is not defined
```

Comment: The recommended shebang for Python is `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

Comment: Something appears wrong with your post - from what I can see, it wouldn't compile. For example, the line after the `def sysloglogging():` is not indented. Also, your code in `consolelogging()` doesn't appear to do anything useful, as the definitions in there are local to that function. The logging docs show you how to arrange logging across multiple modules - see http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html#logging-from-multiple-modules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`log` is a global variable in the `differentlogging` module. Thus you can access it as
`clusterlogging.differentlogging.log`.

You could also do something like `from clusterlogging.differentlogging import log` and then access it as just `log`.

*Edit:* actually, on reviewing your code again I don't know what to make of it. Could you please fix up your code indentation so that it makes sense? Are you defining `log` inside the `consolelogging` function? If so, you'll need to either make it global with `global log` or return it from the function and assign it to a variable `log` on the line where you call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your `main.py` doesn't do anything to define the name `log` in the global namespace.  Importing a module can define names in the namespace of that module, but can't put anything in the global namespace.

In your `main.py` you should add this statement:

```
from clusterlogging.differentlogging import log
```

By the way, I that is such a long module name, I would use `import as`:

```
import clusterlogging.differentlogging as difflogging
log = difflogging.log
```

EDIT: I originally recommended this but it won't work:

```
from difflogging import log  # doesn't work
```

You might even want to use a really short name like `dl`:

```
import clusterlogging.differentlogging as dl
dl.log('whatever')
```

Since `dl` is really short, maybe you don't need to get `log` bound in the global namespace.

Also, you could get every name from a module by using `import *` but this is not recommended.

```
from clusterlogging.differentlogging import *  # not recommended
```

You usually don't want to clutter the global namespace with all the stuff defined in a module.  Import just what you need.  This is tidier and helps document what you are actually using.

Comment: `import clusterlogging.differentlogging as difflogging ; from difflogging import log` is an error. Importing a module using `as` only changes the name it is given in the importing namespace; it's still stored by the full name in `sys.modules`.

Comment: I tried, from clusterlogging.differentlogging import log, and got: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'log'.  The full solution to my problem is posted below

Comment: Then do it this way: `import clusterlogging.differentlogging as difflogging; log = difflogging.log`  Sorry that I posted something that didn't work.  Usually I test my code but I don't have this `clusterlogging`.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the log array, and you will be able to use the logging function associated.

main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

sys.path.append('CLUSTER')
import clusterlogging.differentlogging
log=clusterlogging.differentlogging.ttylogging()

log.debug("Logging module loaded")
log.info ("It worked")
```

differentlogging.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def ttylogging():
    print "Console Logging loaded"
    import sys
    import logging
    class NullHandler(logging.Handler):
        def emit(self, record):
            pass

    DEFAULTLOGLEVEL=logging.INFO
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    log.addHandler(NullHandler())

    log.setLevel(DEFAULTLOGLEVEL)
    logStreamHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    logStreamHandler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(levelname)5s %(name)s %(lineno)d: %(message)s"))
    log.addHandler(logStreamHandler)

    return log  

def mysqllogging():
    print "mysql logging module here"

def sysloglogging():
    print "rsyslog logging module here"
```